# Displaying if there are redundant characters in a string with a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am wondering how you would display if there are redundant characters in a string with a list. Let me explain better. Say you have a list with "_" symbols representing a blank space:

```
word = ["_","_","_","_"]
```

Now say you have a string:

```
string = "door"
```

Let's say you want the user to guess what the word is by inputting characters Hangman-style. If their guess is right, you want that character to be in the "word" array in the same spot it is in the string, so if they guess "d", the "word" list would look like this:

```
word = ["d","_""_""_"]
```

It would print out too look like "d _ _ _". I have no problems up to this point, however when displaying redundant characters I have a problem. For example, if the user guesses "o", I can't seem to display both "o"s in "door" with the array, it always looks like this:

```
word = ["_", "o", "_", "_"]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
word = ["_", "o", "o", "_"]
```

Now please note that this question is very similar to my last one, except that that one didn't explain how to display them in a list. I also am unsure if this has been asked before, I have not found any similar questions but there still may be some. I'm just so confused I don't know what else to do! Thank you for your time. If I've broken a stackoverflow commandment by asking this, I apologize.

Comment: show us the code that's making word `["_", "o", "_", "_"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the word each time:

```
ans = 'door'
word = ['_' for _ in ans]

while '_' in word:
    guess = raw_input('Guess a char')
    for i, c in enumerate(ans):
        if guess.lower() == c.lower():
            word[i] = c
    print word
```

To avoid case problems, use `str.lower` on both input and `c`.

Output:

```
Guess a char
d
['d', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a char
o
['d', 'o', 'o', '_']
Guess a char
r
['d', 'o', 'o', 'r']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the way you are currently modifying the `word`? To make sure that every character will show up you can iterate through `string`: if the letter at index `i` in `string` is equal to the guess, set `word[i] = guess`. This ensures all letters will be caught.

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice to see what code you have so far to be able to point you to the right direction, but have a look at this:

```
def check_guess(word, guessed_character, guess_list):
    if guessed_character in word:
        for index, character in enumerate(word):
            if guessed_character == character:
                guess_list[index] = character

    return guess_list

WORD = 'door'
guess_list = ['_'] * len(WORD)

while '_' in guess_list:
    guessed_character = raw_input()
    print '{}'.format(check_guess(WORD, guessed_character, guess_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I wanted to see if I could get this to be a one liner:

```
string = 'door'
guesses = ['o'] # fill this in as you get guesses
word = [i in guesses and i or '_' for i in string]
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. A bit trigger happy today obviously.

Comment: @SteinarLima freaked me out for a second there :P

Answer (score 0):

```
word = 'door'
blanks = ['_' for x in word] # easy way to generate blanks from word
guess = 'o'
[guess if x == guess else '_' for x in word] #=> ['_','o','o','_']
```